# $y_{n+1} = y_n - \frac{y_n^2}{3}$ general formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I have an induction formula $y_{n+1} = y_n - \frac{y_n^2}{3}$ with $y_0=1$. Is there a way to get the general formula for $y_n$ from this?

Comment: Calculate the first few terms and see if you can identify a pattern. Note that $y_n$ goes to zero as $n$ approaches infinity (by assuming that $y_n$ approaches some constant value).

Comment: I tried, could recognize any pattern: 1, 2/3, 14/27, 14x67/3^7

Comment: The best I could do is the upper bound $y_n \le \dfrac{3}{n+3}$. Let me know if you want to see a proof of this.

Comment: Moreover, one should prove rather easily that $$y_n \sim \frac{3}{n}.$$ Let me know if you want a proof of this ;)